# Python Selenium - How to detect a button click?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

The driver on my script is set on a website with a simple button that performs an ajax action.
Once the user is clicking the button, **the ajax request is being sent without any reaction on the client side UI.**
Is there a way to detect when the client is pressing the button?
No form is being sent, nothing actually happens with the client code, just a button click.

With javascript, I could use onClick event for that, but I can't think of a way to do it with selenium.
I'm looking for something like that;

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clicked((By.ID, 'updateServer')))
doSomething()
```

Just like

```
<button id="updateServer" onClick="doSomething()" />
```

Of course I want doSomething() to be a python function.

Comment: Is this selenium related? How does a "user" click on a button if you're testing via selenium?

Comment: @tytopoo yes I did mean to ask you. You will not be able to use selenium to detect the click of other users.

Comment: So absolutely nothing at all changes. Even the DOM of the page doesn't change?

Comment: @DMart Yes it is, selenium is able to show a browser (web driver) to the "user" and follow its actions.

Comment: This is a VERY odd thing to want to do. I can't understand the problem you're trying to solve. It's odd to expect a human to interact with a selenium script.

Comment: @Dmart Odd for you, I develop many tools with selenium that requires human interaction for my customers, it helps them a lot.

Comment: @DMart for example, you might want to have a script that gets a page loaded in a desktop browser, fields populated and then waits for the user to take some action on the page before continuing the script. Sort of like "hot keys" or "recorded mouse and keyboard actions" except we would like to be able to say "wait until this element has been clicked..."

Answer (score 0):

Just use `execute_script` function:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("updateServer").click()')
```

Comment: The user (the client) has to click the button by himself, I don't want to do it for him. I do want to know when he does it.

Comment: @ifrag are you hosting the website?

Comment: @Jortega Did you mean to ask me? I don't host the website.

Comment: @tytopoo Oh, sorry! I missed this. It doesn't seem so easy. The solution that I see is to add a simple server and override the button's onclick function by adding a call to your server, which will cause the necessary callback in python
Also, I think we have to use websockets to avoid blocking by CORS, so
example js:
```conn = new WebSocket("localhost:8090/");
conn.on_onopen = function (evt) {
conn.send('your data');
conn.close();
}```
And add handler for websocket in your python script.

Comment: @tytopoo I can supplement the answer with code if this solution is acceptable for you

Comment: I understand your answer, it's too long for my need. I came here to find an easier answer, but it seems to be impossible. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: is there really no possible way to do this? although this does not seem to be working properly in my own tests, probably because it does not wait to listen for JS events, what about `clicked = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].onclick = () => true', elem)`?